# creating a wrapper function that takes several different formats of data and passes them to another function as a bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, parameters, type-conversion

I have a function that takes as input a bytearray and a socket, then determines where to send the bytearray using the socket and sends it.  I also have a wrapper for that function, that adds some other data from elsewhere in the containing class to the bytearray and then passes it on.  here's the thing - I'd like that wrapper to be able to take a few different formats instead of just a bytearray, and then pass the data on as a bytearray to the core function.  the formats I'd like to be able to use are:

- a bytearray (obviously)
- an int (either decimal, ie 10, or hex, ie 0x0a)
- a hex string (ie 'abcd1234')
- a boolean

what's the best way to approach this?  the only approach I've had any success with is using nested try/except blocks that each assume a different format, which I know is not how those are supposed to be used, or adding an additional parameter that specifies the datatype, which is just not optimal for maintainability.  I haven't been able to find a similar question on SO, or an example elsewhere online.  if anyone can explain the 'correct' way to handle this, I'd be supremely grateful.  thanks in advance.

here's my solution with try/except (with all the processing not relevant to the problem removed):

```
def wrapper_func(val, sock):
    res = None
    try:
        res = bytearray(bytes([int(val)]))
        print('first worked for ' + str(val))
    except:
        try:
            res = bytearray.fromhex(val)
            print('second worked for ' + str(val))
        except:
            res = val
            print('third worked for ' + str(val))
    # add some additional stuff onto the bytearray
    my_func(res, sock)
```